# Where does the max length of 255 for CHAR fields come from?

Tags: mysql

I mean 255 doesn't look very natural in the context of computer science.

I guess it's related to 256, which makes much more sense in the same context, but I wonder how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one byte = 8 bits. 2 ^ 8 == 256 distinct values, but you have to handle 0, so the range is 0-255.

Comment: Please, help me understand - how is CHAR handling 0 - if you set the length of a CHAR to 0 would that require a byte to store?

Comment: To explain further, this is traditionally implemented as a 1-byte length indicator at the start of a string, as managed by the software in a data structure, but not returned as part of the string itself. Not sure of the specifics in MySQL, but I assume this is why.

Comment: @zanlok: 1-byte for up to 255 bytes, 2 bytes over that limit (*not necessarily 255 characters!* - with multibyte characters, you can get over 255 bytes in less than 80 characters). See the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: @Piskvor: indeed, mentioning multibyte is useful as well. But, I wasn't crafting a full answer, just contributing :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

> CHAR(M)   M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set
>   VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)  L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes

`CHAR` is a fixed-length type - it will always store the maximum length of a string, regardless if the string uses it all up; it will however store the real string length using 1 more byte.

`VARCHAR` is variable-length, and it will store only as many bytes as needed, plus one or two bytes to keep their length. This comes to maximum of 255 bytes for characters, and 1 byte for their length, or 65533 bytes for characters plus 2 bytes for their length.